# Why is a variables that I declared in main being initialized as if it was a variable for my class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Here is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class classTwo
{
public:
    //constructors
    classTwo();
    classTwo(const char chars[101]);

private:

    char classTwoArray[101];

};

//default classTwo constructor
classTwo::classTwo()
{
    strcpy(classTwoArray, "no data");
}

//other classTwo constructor
classTwo::classTwo(const char thisArray[101])
{
strcpy(this->classTwoArray, thisArray);

}

class classOne
{
public:
    //default constructor
    classOne();

    // function
    void functionOne(const classTwo& classTwoObject);

private:
    classTwo hundredObjects[99];
    int size;
};

//classOne default constructor
classOne::classOne()
{
    size = 0;
}

int main(){
    classTwo object;
    char charArray[101];
    string lemmeSee;

    cout << charArray << endl;
    cin >> lemmeSee;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what happens when I run this program:

[image]
So I have two questions:

1) Why is charArray filled with "no data," which is supposed to be for the classTwoArray? I noticed this only happens when I include classTwo object in main.

2) What are those symbols before "no data?" I get those same symbols when I comment out the line //classTwoObject, except that in that case instead of "no data" they're followed by a few other symbols ($ and a few others, which I understand is the result of couting an empty array, but I don't understand why the ones that look like brackets and line show up in either case).

Comment: `charArray` is uninitialized, so your program invokes undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char charArray[101];` is uninitialized - that means that is may be filled with anything. Both `charArray` and `object` lie on stack and compiler put `object` after `charArray` in a stack. When you output `charArray` to a `cin` it tries to output every symbol before it encounters `0`. Because there were no zeroes in `charArray` (it just happened), it continued on outputting symbols and stumbled upon a memory where `object` lies. There were `0` and the end of the `object` and so it stopped outputting anything. You may fix your problem by writing `char charArray[101] = {};`, it will zero-initialize it.

Comment: That also explains why we see the `"no data"` only when `classTwo object` is in the `main()`!

Answer (score 3):

The `chararray` in main() is not initialized. Using uninitialized variables causes undefined behavior.

You can make speculation what happens and why you get exactly that message. But it's *undefined*.